# What is the most efficient way to replace the last occurrence of a string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

String.replace replaces the first occurrence of a string in a string, but I'd like to replace the last occurrence of a string in a string. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [lastIndexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#lastIndexOf%28%29) function to determine where the string you want to replace is, and then add the substring before and after the occurance to get your desired result.

Comment: Well, this is what I have: 
    `private function replaceLastOccurrence($str:String, $find:String, $replace:String):String
        {
            var pre:String = $str.substr(0, $str.lastIndexOf($find)-1),
            post:String = $str.substr($str.lastIndexOf($find)+2, $str.length);
   
            return pre + $replace + post;
        }`
it just doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: True. But as there is no "replaceLast", I think you'll have to live with a not-so-elegant solution. Also, if you make that helper function public and/or static, you'll never see its code again if you use it ;)

Comment: There is an error in the suggested function... here is the corrected one:
public static function replaceLastOccurrence(str:String, find:String, replace:String):String {
var pre:String = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(find)-1);
var post:String = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(find)+find.length, str.length); 
return pre + replace + post;
}

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the suggested function... here is the corrected one:

```
public static function replaceLastOccurrence(str:String, find:String, replace:String):String {
    var pre:String = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(find));
    var post:String = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(find)+find.length, str.length); 

    return pre + replace + post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if there is an occurance at all:

```
public static function replaceLastOccurrence(str:String, find:String, replace:String):String  
{
    if (str.lastIndexOf(find) != -1)
    {
        var pre:String = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(find));
        var post:String = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(find) + find.length, str.length); 
        return pre + replace + post;
    }
    else
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

otherwise it will mess up the ending of the string if there is no occurance.